# How do I prevent this FFmpeg scale command from removing the 'Date taken' metadata?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, photos, exif

How do I prevent this FFmpeg command from removing the 'Date taken' (and other) metadata from JPG photographs?

```
ffmpeg -i "Input.JPG" -vf scale=iw*.5:-1 -update true "Output.jpg"
```

FWIW, I tried combinations of `-movflags use_metadata_tags` and `-map_metadata 0` but with no success.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using a video tool like FFmpeg to process static images? I recommend you simply use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/) instead; purely command line static image editing and well regraded.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Why are there so many on this forum who come here to finger wag instead of helping provide a solution to the actual question?

Comment: Why do you consider it “finger wagging” to recommend you use the correct tool for the task at hand? Everything I am reading says that `-movflags use_metadata_tags` and `-map_metadata 0` is strictly for videos and in the case of JPEGs you need to use an external tool like ExifTool to transfer metadata. This question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70873158/117259) is similar to yours. This [blog post](http://www.note.id.lv/2016/02/scale-keep-metadata-ffmpeg-exiftool.html) implies the same. ImageMagick just naturally transfers all metadata.

Comment: @Giacomo1968  Even simply listing an image's metadata doesn't seem possible with `ffmpeg`/`ffprobe`.  All the list metadata `ffmpeg` commands I searched for and tried only list data as if the image was a stream.  It seems quite likely that `ffmpeg` simply can't read any image metadata.